# Show that if $f'$ is increasing on $(a,b)$, then $f'$ is continuous on $(a,b)$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

> Let $a < b$ and $f : [a, b] \to \mathbb R$ be differentiable on $[a, b]$. Show that,
>
> (i) if $f'$ is increasing on $(a,b)$, then $f'$ is continuous on $(a,b)$.

I have seen this exercise question in the lecture notes, but I am confused. The statement we want to prove only has the derivative $f'$ but no $f$. Am I supposed to use a property of derivatives?

Comment: You need to show $\lim_{x\to\alpha}f'(x)=f'(\alpha)$. You can do this using the definition of $f'(\alpha)$ plus the Mean Value Theorem...

Comment: Do you know that monotone functions can only have jump discontinuity? And further derivatives can't have jump discontinuity. Combining them a monotone derivative can't have any discontinuity. You need to prove those two properties I mentioned.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Thanks, I think this way was easier for me to understand.

Comment: Let me know if you need any further help in proving those two properties. The proofs should be available in textbooks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to justify @DavidCUllrich's suggestion for a right-neighborhood $(\alpha, \alpha+\delta)$ of any $\alpha \in (a,b)$.  As the collection of such neighborhood $\{(\alpha,\alpha+\delta)\}_{\alpha\in(a,b)}$ covers the open interval $(a,b)$, then we're done.

1. Apply MVT on the interval $[\alpha+\delta,\alpha+2\delta]$ to establish a point $\xi \in (\alpha+\delta,\alpha+2\delta)$ such that $$f'(\xi) = \frac{f(\alpha+2\delta)-f(\alpha+\delta)}{\delta}.$$
2. Use the given condition that $f'$ is increasing to conclude that
   $$f'(\alpha) \le f'(\alpha+\delta) \le f'(\xi).$$
   Combine the result of step 1 to see that we need to establish a relationship between the difference quotient in step 1 and $f'(\alpha)$.  Once that's done, we may apply the Sandwich Theorem to conclude.
3. Rewrite the difference quotient in step 1 as
   \begin{align}
   f'(\xi) &= \frac{f(\alpha+2\delta)-f(\alpha+\delta)}{\delta} \\
   &= 2\;\frac{f(\alpha+2\delta)-f(\alpha)}{2\delta} - \frac{f(\alpha+\delta) - f(\alpha)}{\delta}.
   \end{align}
4. Then take limit as $\delta \to 0$.  This is possible as $f$ is differentiable on $[a,b]$.  It's not hard to see that the RHS tends to $2f'(\alpha) - f'(\alpha) = f'(\alpha)$.
5. Apply the Sandwich Theorem to conclude.